# Auto scroll to div id on page load

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

So I've got my page set up with an intro section, and after a set time the browser auto scrolls to a specified div which works correctly. What I'd like to do is have it run when the page is fully loaded as opposed to immediately.
This is the existing code which works fine.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $('#myDiv').offset().top}, 2800);
});
},1300);
```

And this is what I've tried to make it run on page load instead of immediately. Which stops the scroll altogether

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $('#myDiv').offset().top}, 2800);
});
},1300);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wrap your scroll function in $(function() {...}), because I think that this could cause the error

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(‘#myDiv’).offset().top}, 2800);
});
```

You can also use document.ready, to scroll the page when the DOM has succesfully loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(‘#myDiv’).offset().top}, 2800);
});
```

Comment: @Paolo Thanks for helping

Comment: This is not doing the trick. The auto scroll function has stopped completely. This is a page I've added your suggested code to http://dmc.ninja/hci.html

Comment: and this is one I've got the existing code on http://dmc.ninja/about.html

Comment: @macker it scrolls in my browser. how much do you want it to scroll?

Comment: Maybe try using another browser, in safari it works just fine, it scrolls down to #project

Comment: Darius is that the about page or the hci.html?

Comment: it's about hci.html

Comment: yeah the about page has my original code, the problem being it auto scrolls immediately instead of on page load. the hci.html is the one i've added the ops suggested code to, which now doesn't scroll

Comment: As I said, you use $(document).ready to wait for DOM loading, and $(window).load otherwise

Comment: You could also use a setTimeout function

Comment: I have used setTimeout in the original code. My understanding is that using $(document).ready will execute the function immediately instead of waiting for the page to load

Comment: Hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If don't have to wrap the inner function into `$(function(){...})`

Furthermore you're passing to `load` a parameter that's not expected.

Just let the "scroll to div" code be the handler to the `load` event.

Finally just apply animate to the `'body'` or even just `window`

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#myDiv').offset().top}, 2800);
} );
```